# Multiple Table View with different arrays

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a detail view that shows the details of an event, the people who participate and the people who asked to participate. I have created two arrays of different types but they have the same fields, only that a first structure represents the users with the 'status_confirm' field equal to 1 (therefore Accepted Users), while the other has as 'status_confirm' equal to 0 (Users awaiting acceptance). I declared two arrays, the first one: `var arrayUserAccepted = [User_accepted] ()`.
The second one: `var arrayUserWaiting = [User_waiting] ()`. [Struct Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESsFQ.png)
Next step: I populate these structures via a php script

```
func getData(){
    let url = URL(string: “MYURL”)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
        print("JSON: \n\(json)\n")
        let waiting = json["waiting"] as! [AnyObject]
        let accepted = json["accepted"] as! [AnyObject]
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            for list_user_waiting in waiting {
                let id_user_waiting = list_user_waiting["id_user”] as! String
                let name_user_waiting = list_user_waiting[“name_user”] as! String
                let email_user_waiting = list_user_waiting["email"] as! String
                var photo_user_waiting = list_user_waiting[“photo”]
                let status_user_waiting = list_user_waiting["status”] as! String
                if photo_user_waiting is NSNull {
                    photo_user_waiting = ""
                }
                let listUserWaiting = User_waiting(id_user_waiting: id_user_waiting, name_user_waiting: name_user_waiting, email_user_waiting: email_utente_attesa, foto_waiting: photo_user_waiting as! String, status_waiting: status_user_waiting)
                self.arrayUserWaiting.append(listUserWaiting)
                self.tableViewListUserWaiting.reloadData()
            }

            for list_user_accepted in accepted {
                let id_user_accepted = list_user_accepted["id_utente"] as! String
                let name_user_accepted = list_user_accepted["name_utente"] as! String
                let email_user_accepted = list_user_accepted["email"] as! String
                var photo_user_accepted = list_user_accepted[“photo"]
                let status_user_accepted = list_user_accepted["status”] as! String
                if photo_user_accepted is NSNull {
                    photo_user_accepted = ""
                }
                let listUserAccepted = User_accepted(id_user: id_user_accepted, nome_utente: name_user_accepted, email: email_user_accepted, foto: photo_user_accepted as! String, stato: status_user_accepted)
                self.arrayUserAccepted.append(listUserAccepted)
                self.tableViewListUserAccepted.reloadData()
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}).resume()}
```

This above is a function that I call in the viewDidLoad(). The next step would be to use the functions of the table view and it is here that I think there is the injunction

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count: Int?
    if tableView == self.tableViewListUserAccepted {
        count = arrayUserAccepted.count
    }
    if tableView == self.tableViewListUserWaiting {
        count = arrayUserWaiting.count
    }
    return count!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    if tableView == self.tableViewListUserAccepted {
        cell.imageProfileUserAccepted.image = UIImage(named: "imageDefault")
        cell.valueSliderUserAccepted.value = Float(50) //JUST FOR POPULATE THE INTERFACE
        cell.name_user_accepted.text = arrayUserAccepted[indexPath.row].name_user
    } 
    if tableView == self.tableViewListUserWaiting {
        cell.imageProfileUserWaiting.image = UIImage(named: "imageDefault")
        cell.valueSliderUserWaiting.value = Float(23) //JUST FOR POPULATE THE INTERFACE
        cell.name_user_waiting.text = arrayUserWaiting[indexPath.row].name_user_waiting
    }
    return cell
}
```

Once done all this round, I start the application but nothing. The tables are empty. In the console the script answers me correctly and so I can not figure out where the error could be. Needless to say, I have declared the .delegate and .dataSource of both tables, both in the Main.Storyboard and in the code.

Comment: For a start, I'd get some breakpoints in there and try and chase the flow. Is getData() getting into the do{} section, or is it getting an error and returning at the guard? Can you see users being created and added to the arrays? Incidentally I'd take the reloadData() call outside of the loop, but that shouldn't be an error.

Comment: Have you set datasource for both `UITableView `

Comment: One more thing don't reload tableviews in `for` loop

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Yes, i did and i leave reloadData in the func getData() and write it in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine just change the format of IF condition and it will work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count: Int?
    if tableView == self.tableViewListUserAccepted {
        count = arrayUserAccepted.count
    } else {
        count = arrayUserWaiting.count
    }
    return count!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == self.tableViewListUserAccepted {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.imageProfileUserAccepted.image = UIImage(named: "imageDefault")
        cell.valueSliderUserAccepted.value = Float(50) //JUST FOR POPULATE THE INTERFACE
        cell.name_user_accepted.text = arrayUserAccepted[indexPath.row].name_user
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.imageProfileUserWaiting.image = UIImage(named: "imageDefault")
        cell.valueSliderUserWaiting.value = Float(23) //JUST FOR POPULATE THE INTERFACE
        cell.name_user_waiting.text = arrayUserWaiting[indexPath.row].name_user_waiting
        return cell
    }

}
```

Also check if the `datasource` and `delegate` of both of your `tableView` are set. Finally call the `tableView.reloadTable()` method on both of your tableviews after you populate your arrays in the `viewDidLoad()` method.

Comment: No, it did not work. It makes me display the blank lines. I'm going crazy  :\

Comment: try reloating the tableViews outside of the DispatchQueue and in the viewDidLoad() after your arrays are being populated.